# What is the semantics of this "do ... end"

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and am learning from reading an already written code.
I encounter this code:

```
label = TkLabel.new(@root) do
    text 'Current Score: '   
    background 'lightblue'
end
```

What is the semantics of the syntax "do" above?
I played around with it and it seems like creating a TkLabel object then set its class variable text and background to be what specified in quote. However when I tried to do the same thing to a class I created, that didn't work.

Oh yeah, also about passing hash into function, such as

```
object.function('argument1'=>123, 'argument2'=>321)
```

How do I make a function that accepts that kind of argument?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking at is commonly referred to as a DSL, or Domain Specific Language.

At first glance it may not be clear why the code you see works, as `text` and `background` are seemingly undefined, but the trick here is that that code is actually evaluated in a scope in which they are.  At it's simplest, the code driving it might look something like this:

```
class TkLabel
  def initialize(root, &block)
    @root = root

    if block
      # the code inside the block in your app is actually
      # evaluated in the scope of the new instance of TkLabel
      instance_eval(&block)
    end
  end

  def text(value)
    # set the text
  end

  def background(value)
    # set the background
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Second question first: that's just a hash. Create a function that accepts a single argument, and treat it like a hash.

The "semantics" are that `initialize` accepts a block (the `do...end` bit), and some methods accepting string parameters to set specific attributes.

Without knowing how you tried to do it, it's difficult to go much beyond that. Here are a [few](http://www.snowfrog.net/2011/08/30/ruby-blocks-and-procs/), [possible](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/), [references](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/07/the-building-blocks-of-ruby/) that might help you over some initial hurdles.

Ruby is pretty decent at making miniature, [internal DSLs](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InternalDslStyle.html) because of its ability to accepts blocks and its forgiving (if arcane at times) syntax.

Comment: Hi, how about the function where some of its arguments are in form of hash and some others are just regular arguments. I encountered this kind of function call. Any idea about how to implement it? An example would be really appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: @BlackSoil That'll just be a method with multiple parameters, if there's a single hash, put it at the end--the caller doesn't need the bracket. If there are multiple hashes, or the hash isn't the last argument, the caller needs brackets for all but the last one (hash).